# Can't share my WordPress post with my image on Facebook

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-opengraph, sharing

I have a problem sharing my posts on Facebook from my WordPress site.
When I share it to Facebook I get some weird Japanese picture.
I've checked solutions  online but none of them worked for me. here is a list of what I've done:

I have deactivated all the plugins to see that there is no conflict. I have downloaded the following plugins (downloaded and activated one at a time of course):

1. Facebook Thumb Fixer
2. ultimate-social-media-plus
3. mashsharer
4. open-graph-protocol-framework
5. wp-facebook-open-graph-protocol
6. facebook Plugin
7. simple-facebook-og-image
8. Facebook Open Graph,Google+ and Twitter Card Tags
9. All in one SEO
10. Yoast Seo (Enabled the facebook button and set an feature image in the post page)

Also:

- removed cache from the browser
  *tried the facebook developer including fetching again.
- tried to paste the link directly to facebook
- tried to put feature image (there are pictures also in the media library)
- tried to share a brand new post, same results
- Uploaded the picture with their desired dimentions of 1200*630

Again and again I'm getting the message that og:image og:title and are missing

The link is:
http://www.tipsforeasyphotography.com/lightroom/creating-editing-panorama-lightroom-photoshop-inc-presets-virtual-copies-export

http://www.tipsforeasyphotography.com/lightroom/library/test-facebook-200x200   (with feature image of 200 by 200)

Comment: Note from the close reasons: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**_. Links are not a substitute for this - would you edit your question?

Answer (score 0):

As you have tried several solutions for this and none did work, There may be some problem in your DNS settings. In the Facebook debugger, it returns 206 status code. This following link debugs a nearly similar scenario [LINK](https://bestwebtuts.com/how-to-fix-facebook-debugger-206-response-code/).

Comment: Hey @Mamun, i looked at the DNS and i see that i only have A and not AAAA. im working on enabling the right click. i would be more than happy if you have any other suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: @AvishaiZarfati, As I've looked whois for your domain, I noticed you have NS & A both records enabled. Try removing the A keep the NS only. Wait & check to see if it works. :)

Comment: I talked to bluehost and they said that i cant delete the A and keep the NS, they say i need both of them

Comment: I put my link on google search console and i also get the japaneese. does it mean that its not facebook at all and its my wordpress theme or something thats the problem? Im waiting for them to respond

Comment: Yes, it is not the problem with facebook. Somewhere in the DNS or Wordpress or in between.

Comment: I assume it is affecting all the crawlers like if you check in the google pagespeed or gtmetrix or in pingdom same error everywhere. [pagespeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tipsforeasyphotography.com%2F&tab=desktop),  [gtmetrix](https://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.tipsforeasyphotography.com/LKCD3JAc), [pingdom](https://tools.pingdom.com/#!/bOay9T/http://www.tipsforeasyphotography.com/)

Comment: Can you please share your '.htaccess" file for the website.

Comment: # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Comment: Solved! my site was hacked. I solved that and facebook got the right image.

Comment: Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Good to hear that @AvishaiZarfati. Can you please let us know how did you fix it? for your future reference. Thanks

Comment: I installed wordfence and ran a scan. i had a problem with my index.php file.

Answer (score 0):

You have a script to avoid the right click and hide the source code of your page, but it also work for any **scraper**.

Try to disable it for the facebook **scraper**.

I also think like @Mamun, that you can have an issue with your dns, that you need to verify.

Comment: The FB scraper does not care about any client-side JS.